# Invalid Handle windows debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I'mworking on simple debugger on windows. 
When I tried to get context of thread I need, GetLastError return me error code 6 which means that the handle of thread is invaild, but I dont have idea why.

Dbg header

```
class PDbg
{
public:
    PDbg() = default;
    ~PDbg();
    bool StartDebugActiveProcess(DWORD processId);
    bool StartDebugNewProcess(LPTSTR processName);
    bool AddBreakpoint(LPVOID address, HANDLE hProecss, PBreakpointHandler pbreakpoint_handler = NULL);
    bool RemoveBreakpoint(LPVOID address, HANDLE hProcess);
    bool SetThreadTrapFlag(DWORD threadId);
    bool Shutdown();

private:
    DWORD _startupProcessId;
    LPVOID _image_base; 
    DWORD _image_size;
    std::map<DWORD, HANDLE> _processes; //handle all processes
    std::map<DWORD, HANDLE> _threads; // handle all threads
    std::map<LPVOID, PBreakpoint> _breakpoints; // handle all breakpoints
    std::map<DWORD, LPVOID> _pending_breakpoints; // handle breakpoints to recreate

    void run();
    void handle_create_process_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_create_thread_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_exception_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_load_dll_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_unload_dll_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_output_debug_string(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_exit_thread_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
    void handle_exit_process_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT* dbgEvent);
};
```

CreateProcess method, here I'm getting thread's handle.

```
void PDbg::handle_create_process_debug_event(DEBUG_EVENT * dbgEvent)
{
    printf("Event: Create process, PID: %u, Base address: %p, Start address: %p\n",
        dbgEvent->dwProcessId, dbgEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.lpBaseOfImage, dbgEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.lpStartAddress);

    if (dbgEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.hFile != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(dbgEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.hFile);
    }

    this->_processes[dbgEvent->dwProcessId] = dbgEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess;
    this->_threads[dbgEvent->dwThreadId] = dbgEvent->u.CreateThread.hThread;

}
```

SetTreadContext method, where I try to change thread's context

```
bool PDbg::SetThreadTrapFlag(DWORD threadId)
{
    const unsigned int k86trapflag = (1 << 8);
    CONTEXT ctx;
    memset(&ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));

    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;

    auto x = this->_threads;
    if (!GetThreadContext(this->_threads[threadId], &ctx))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot get thread context. Error:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        return FALSE;
    }

    ctx.EFlags |= k86trapflag;

    if (!SetThreadContext(this->_threads[threadId], &ctx))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot set thread context." << std::endl;

        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Method where I call SetTrhreadContext is not important. I'm sure and I checked that the threadId I'm passing to SetTreadContext EXISTS in threads(DWORD, HANDLE) map. So what makes this problem?

Comment: Does this apply _"...You cannot get a valid context for a running thread. ..."_ from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten - at first this is false - we can get context of thread. at second this is unrelated to error- invalid handle

Comment: @RbMm (1) I didn't say it did; I was asking if the information helped the OP. (2) Do you have a reference to refute the MSDN documentation?

Comment: @RichardCritten - refute of what ? *You cannot get a valid context for a running thread* - mean only that get context of running thread have no big sense - context all time changed. but api call must not fail. and your information can not be helped - it absolute unrelated to problem. api return clear error - handle of thread is invalid.

Comment: if you write debugger - you must able to debug your code :) which handle value you use when api call fail ? which handle value you save for this thread id ? begin from this

Comment: @RbMm Did you actually read the doc?  Quoting a bit further _"...You cannot get a valid context for a running thread. Use the SuspendThread function to suspend the thread before calling GetThreadContext. ..."_  And as there was no call to `SuspendThread` in the question I was just wondering if OP had considered this, or had the code already suspended all the threads in the process being debugged.

Comment: @RichardCritten - not need any suspendthread calls. if handle is valid - we got context. if handle is invalid we got such error. suspendthread absolute not affect this. and as side note - when debugger receiver events - all threads in process already suspended. but how i say this unrelated to error - **error code 6 which means that the handle of thread is invaild**

Comment: @RbMm I think that I foud the bug in my code. In handle_create_process_debug_event I should get thread's handle from CreateProcess union's field insted CreateThread.

Comment: @bielu000 - yes, you need use `dbgEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.hThread` on create process event. this is all explain

Comment: I have one more thing. When I override original instruction byte with 0xcc, and after caputring the this breakpoint should I decrement  EIP register?